# Instant switching between threads in Unity

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, synchronization

I'm working on a checkers AI. When it is the AI's turn, I activate an `ActiveSearch` for the best move in an `_activeSearchThread`, while if it's the opponent's turn, I activate a `PassiveSearch` in a `_passiveSearchThread`. **Passive Search** guesses the opponent's move and searches for the respond.

The problem is my AI class has a list of transpositions used *in both threads*. When the opponent makes their move, I interrupt the `passive search` thread and activate the **active search**. However, `Thread.Interrupt` does not function *immediately*: it only interrupts a thread if it's ["in the WaitSleepJoin state"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.interrupt?view=netframework-2.0). Thus, it might happen that the active search is already on, but the passive search is not off yet. Both of them try to use the list of transpositions, which causes an error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

So is there a way to get the active search thread started **only after having made sure** the passive one has **really** been interrupted?

---

This code conveys the ai's decisions to the game manager and manages the threads.

```
    public void PerformMove (Move move) // Called by the ai when it has made a decision
    {
        OnAiMadeMove?.Invoke(move); // Raises an event that the game manager is subscribed to
    }

    public void ReceiveOpponentsMove (Move move) // Called by the game manager to natify the ai that the opponent has made move
    {
        _passiveSearchThread?.Interrupt(); // Interrupting passive search
        if (_passiveSearchThread != null)
            print(_passiveSearchThread.IsAlive); // *** (see comments below)

        _ai.ReceiveOpponentsMove(move); // Send some data of the opponent's move to the ai

        StartCoroutine(StartActiveSearch()); // Start active search coroutine
    }

    private IEnumerator StartActiveSearch ()
    {
        _ai.PrepareForActiveSearch(_manager.GetCurrentTime(_isWhite)); // Some pre-settings
        _activeSearchThread = new Thread(_ai.FindBestMove); // An active search thread
        _activeSearchThread.Name = "ActiveThread";
        _activeSearchThread.Start(); // Starting it (problem is here: it is guaranteed that to this moment the passive search is off)

        yield return new WaitWhile(() => _activeSearchThread.IsAlive); // Waiting the ai to make a decision

        // Accepting the ai's decision and sending it to the game manager
        Move move = _ai.GetBestMove();
        PerformMove(move);
        _ai.MoveAccepted(move);
        StartPassiveSearch();
    }
    private void StartPassiveSearch ()
    {
        _passiveSearchThread = new Thread(_ai.PassiveSearch); // A passive search thread
        _passiveSearchThread.Name = "PassiveThread";
        _passiveSearchThread.Start(); // Starting it (when ai has made move and it is the opponent's turn)
    }
```

*** This condition is a check: Debug.Log() here prints ***TRUE***, that means that a passive search thread hasn't yet been interrupted.

Comment: Why are switching between logic paths by stopping one thread and starting another? Is this some new design pattern I've never heard of? Unless two things have to happen at the same time, usually a program would switch between logic paths without switching threads.

Comment: @JohnWu I am relatively a newby in multithreading. As far as I understand, when I create a thread, I set a function that the thread is going to start from. If I only have 1 thread for the ai, then I must call the ActiveSearch function in the end of the PassiveSearch function and vice-versa, isn't it right? I will eventually break the limit of the function depth, won't I?

Comment: Multithreading is considered a difficult discipline, that requires study and practice to master. The behavior of a multithreaded application can become quite bizarre and unintuitive. If you want to write a correct multithreaded application, you shouldn't really relay on your instincts. I would suggest to take a step back, and study threading systematically for a few days before going forward. Here is a good online learning resource: [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) by ​Joseph Albahari.

Comment: You don't need Multithreading in unity for 99.9% of things, you can do whatever you want without it

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thank you for your recommendation and link. I will definitely study it!

Comment: @MiladQasemi How can I if I need the ai to calculate the position (which might take several seconds) and the app to be still responsible, the clocks must countdown and background animations and the rest...

Comment: @МаксимФисман In each frame, everything updates animation, AI , physics and other scripts they all get an update. Things that must happen every frame shouldn't take a long time. If something takes a long time like sending a web request, you can send it async.

Comment: @МаксимФисман there are system like unity [job system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystem.html) that let you write multithread code. you can read about. But forget the normal C# multithreading.